# Ubuntu & Kubuntu in same drive

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, kubuntu

I have ubuntu in one of my drives . Can I install kubuntu in that same drive . 
I am already having a dual boot system . Will it effect MBR ??

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly. Yes, you may set a separate partition and install to that particular partition another OS. This will directly effect the MBR. You will need to upgrade the bootloader.ie:GRUB

The other option is to install the `Kubuntu-Desktop` package in the current Ubuntu OS then log out and select Kubuntu. log back in to a fresh new experience.

To do this using the terminal `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` or use the software center

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install both of them in same harddisk. And it will effect MBR.